# Getting time of execution of request and response in ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Please, I want to use stopwatch to get the seconds from the time of sending of request through ajax and success function.

Comment: Show what you have tried

Comment: see the network tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
var start_time = new Date();
$.ajax({
  // Other params
  success: function () {
    var end_time = new Date();
    alert("Time taken: " seconds(end_time) - seconds(start_time));
  }
});
function seconds(date_obj) {
  return date_obj.getTime();
}
```

Please figure out `seconds()` yourself.

Comment: I want to get the result in form of milliseconds

Comment: @PrinceEsanjuFestusBabatunde Can't you convert it yourself? The answer already gives in milliseconds only. Did you even try?